# Flutter desktop - send PDF to a printer

Tags: bash, flutter, printing, flutter-desktop

I have a requirement to print PDF on the printer from the Flutter app. Is there a chance to have a possibility to do so right now? I mean that my application is going to fetch the PDF file from the server and then I would like to put it directly to the printer, so it can be printed instantly. The platform that I am targetting is windows.

If this is not possible then is there a chance to execute .bat script using flutter? In the case that there would be no such possibility I could make the script that would print expected file to avoid flutter in this functionality

Comment: If it is web flutter it would be possible in flutter desktop I have not tried it.

Comment: I am implementing the desktop application, so it is not web :(

Comment: Try to add: import 'dart:html'; and later onTap button: window.print("http://www.example.com/example.pdf");  I don't know if it works, but try.

Comment: you'll have to write the windows code for that and communicate with it using `MethodChannel`

Comment: @Ryosuke I understand, so I have to modify the Windows project with the custom method to print proper file. Seems to be a thing that will work. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: yeah right now its the only way. unfortunately I wasn't able to find any Windows plugin example. Maybe it's similar to linux that's why they didn't provide it.

Comment: You could also try [go-flutter-desktop](https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter), write the plugin with *go* may be a good option!

Comment: You can try with [flutter-printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

Comment: is there a chance to execute .bat script using flutter? Yes. You can.  please see my post to start Excel with Process.run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143104/flutter-desktop-go-flutter-desktop-open-excel-file-on-windows-platform

Comment: with Process.run and this https://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php#PrintPDF , it might work.

Comment: I contribute go-flutter plugin, for me, I will write a C# program and install in disk  or try to make this C# print as web api and call this web api (,I do not know is it work on web api )

Comment: I am sorry about my spamming. It's possible to do remote printing. https://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/remote-printing-with-asp-net-web-api-in-windows-service/

Comment: @Ryosuke https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/example_plugin has a Windows implementation.

Comment: @Dharmesh That's a plugin; existing Flutter plugins won't work on desktop without porting. See http://flutter.dev/desktop#plugins

Answer (score 0):

Printing support is something you would likely want to implement with a [plugin](https://flutter.dev/desktop#writing-a-plugin).

Comment: The project structure of Flutter for desktop has changed substantially in the last year and a half. I've replaced the answer with the current link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Printing Package ANDROID IOS LINUX MACOS WEB WINDOWS](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)